# Showing cardinality inequalities involving equivalence relations without the Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I am studying a course on ZF Set Theory and am currently looking at the cardinalities of infinite sets.

> Consider any equivalence relation $\equiv$ on any set $X$. Show that  $$2 ^{ |X/{\equiv}|} \leq 2^{|X|} $$ $$\text{and}$$ $$|X/{\equiv}| < 2 ^{|X|}, $$
> without using the Axiom of Choice.

Using the Axiom of Choice for these types of inequalities feels a lot more natural to me, however, without this I am unsure how to proceed.

It feels like a natural way to go about this question is to find an injective function from the left hand set to the right hand set in order to show the that the left hand cardinality is less than or equal to the right hand cardinality (in both cases).

I initially believed that the second part of the question follows on trivially from the first, but I have been led to believe that this is more involved than I first thought and would be grateful for any help or clarification here.

Comment: The injection you need for the first inequality is given by "union": If $Z$ in any set of equivalence classes (i.e., any subset of $X/\equiv$), then the union of those equivalence classes, $\bigcup Z$, is a subset of $X$. And if $Z\neq Z'$ then $\bigcup Z\neq\bigcup Z'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, note that there is a surjection from $X$ onto $X/{\equiv}$. This means that the fibres of this functions define an injection from $X/{\equiv}$ into $2^X$, but you can show that this injective function actually maps $2^{X/{\equiv}}$ into $2^X$ injectively.

For the second one, note that quite literally, $X/{\equiv}$ is a subset of $2^X$, when considering $2^X$ as the power set of $X$. So we trivially get $\leq$. But since there is a surjection from $X$ onto $X/{\equiv}$, this $\leq$ cannot possibly be $=$, since that would contradict Cantor's theorem, which holds without choice (there is no surjection from $X$ onto $2^X$). Therefore $X/{\equiv}<2^X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That clears up a lot of the confusion I had. I’m not sure I follow your first point though. I can see that there is clearly a surjection, but I’m not following the rest of the argument.

Comment: $x\mapsto x/{\equiv}$?

Comment: I didn’t get the point about the fibres defining an injection

Comment: If you have a surjection from $A$ onto $B$, what is the most natural injection from $B$ into $2^A$?

Comment: I understand how this defines an injection, but I can’t see how the function maps $2^{X / \equiv}$ into $2^X$ injectively. I’m only able to see the injection from $ X / \equiv$ into $2^X$ unless I’m missing something

Comment: @FD_bfa: If $f\colon A\to B$ is a surjection, then $F(X)=f^{-1}(X)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in X\}$ is an injection.